# With dual boot where install the GRUB on Debian

Tags: debian, grub

I will ask when to install Debian asked me where to install the GRUB, with only an operating system, it installs on the first hard disk,

> /dev/sda

but with two operating systems, where install it, on

```
/dev/sda
```

or

```
/dev/sd1
```

I ask only for information, i will not do it, i will only learn.

The question with an example, I have Mint Linux on a hard disk and also wants to install Debian , the GRUB from Linux Mint is installed on `/dev/sda`, if installed Debian will ask me where to install the grub, what am I answers? and why?

Comment: Maybe it asked if you wanted to use /sda1, not /sd1 ?  Please go to your question by clicking [edit].   Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can install grub to `/dev/sda` overwriting your Linux Mint's bootloader. The Debian installer's grub should detect your existing Mint installation and add a boot entry for it.

**Option 2:**
You skip the grub installation in the Debian installer and boot into Linux Mint when your installation is complete. Open a terminal and update grub with `sudo update-grub` manually. Grub should find your Debian installation and add a boot entry to your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Then reboot and check if dual boot works as expected.